# Return MAX After Selection

Tags: select, max

I very new to SQL Queries and am having issue with Getting MAX of Column Speedo below is my current query

```
SELECT 
tblVehicle.Rego
,tbljob.Speedo 
,tbljob.DateEntered
from tblJob
INNER JOIN tblVehicle 
 on tbljob.Vehicle_ID = tblVehicle.ID
   where JobType_ID = 2
   order by Rego
```

Which outputs

```
Rego    Speedo  DateEntered
000JKC  147729  2010-05-10 10:56:55.040
000JKC  150145  2010-06-02 13:57:15.470
000JKC  169553  2011-01-06 12:24:09.143
000JKC  155149  2010-07-21 14:58:20.777
000JKC  157882  2010-09-17 16:39:48.480
000JKC  165660  2010-11-29 08:20:39.453
000JKC  164339  2010-11-18 16:19:19.213
000JKC  155149  2010-08-11 06:16:28.180
000RQD  65  2011-11-21 09:27:31.693
000RQD  6978    2012-03-06 15:18:06.987
000RQD  6766    2012-02-24 13:28:47.603
000RQD  12130   2012-08-28 09:29:18.027
000RQD  12145   2012-08-27 14:57:17.330
000RQD  21550   2013-04-15 19:30:30.160
000RQD  23640   2013-05-22 16:16:33.880
```

Now i would just like the MAX(Speedo) of Each Rego Only.

Answer (score 0):

**The MAX() function returns the largest value of the selected column.**

```
SELECT 
tblVehicle.Rego
, MAX( tbljob.Speedo )
,tbljob.DateEntered
from tblJob
INNER JOIN tblVehicle 
 on tbljob.Vehicle_ID = tblVehicle.ID
   where JobType_ID = 2
   order by Rego
```

Comment: With yours i get the following error Column 'tblVehicle.Rego' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
tblVehicle.Rego
,MAX(tbljob.Speedo) as MaxSpeedo
,MAX(tbljob.DateEntered) as MaxDate
from tblJob
INNER JOIN tblVehicle 
 on tbljob.Vehicle_ID = tblVehicle.ID
   where JobType_ID = 2
   order by Rego
GROUP BY Rego
```

Note:  This may not achieve the result you want if the Speedo is wound back, and the last date does not have the maximum for Speedo.  In that scenario you will see the maximum speedo, and the maximum date, but they are coming from different rows.